# What difference between gitignore in android studio and GTLab?

Tags: android, git

In my project android in android Studio in have the file .gitignore or in  my Gitlab it is necessery to create .gitignore.
What is the difference between .gitignore in android studio and .gitignore in Gitlab?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are not different types of .gitignore files, there are .gitignore files with different rules within it. You create a .gitignore file for your project and there you define the rules for files you want to be ignored.

You do not need to create .gitignore file for Android Studio and another for Gitlab, you need to create a .gitignore file for your project.

Comment: Thanks,i will create .gitignore in my project